# Mudança de idioma com JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Estou desenvolvendo um site e ele terá dois idiomas. Para isso, montei um JSON que muda os idiomas clicando no *select box* da linguagem correspondente. No entanto, o código não funciona e nem mostra erro no console.

Segue o código:

```js
var arrLang = {
  'en' : {
      'home' : 'Home',
      'sobre' : 'About us',
      'equipe' : 'Team',
      'ferramentas' : 'Tools',
      'exchanges' : 'Supported Exchanges',
      'contato' : 'Contact',
  },
  'pt' : {
      'home' : 'Home',
      'sobre' : 'Quem somos',
      'equipe' : 'Equipe',
      'ferramentas' : 'Ferramentas',
      'exchanges' : 'Exchanges Suportadas',
      'contato' : 'Contato',
  }
};

$(function(){
  $('#year').change(function(){
      var lang = $(this).attr('id');

      $('.lang').each(function(index, element){
          $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="language">
  <select id="year">
      <option value="pt" id="pt">PT</option>
      <option value="en" id="en">EN</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active" data-menuanchor="home">
            <a class="nav-link lang" href="#home" key="home">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item"  data-menuanchor="quem-somos">
            <a class="nav-link lang" href="#quem-somos" key="sobre">Quem Somos</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item"  data-menuanchor="equipe">
            <a class="nav-link lang" href="#equipe" key="equipe">Equipe</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item"  data-menuanchor="ferramentas">
            <a class="nav-link lang" href="#ferramentas" key="ferramentas">Ferramentas</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item"  data-menuanchor="exchanges">
            <a class="nav-link lang" href="#exchanges" key="exchanges">Exchanges Suportadas</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item"  data-menuanchor="contato" key="contato">
            <a class="nav-link lang" href="#contato">Contato</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está nessa linha do seu código JavaScript:

> ```
> var lang = $(this).attr('id');
> ```

Para capturar o `value` de um `select` no evento `change` do jQuery, basta usar o `$(this).val()`.

Portanto, o correto é:

```
var lang = $(this).val();
```

E o código final:

```js
var arrLang = {
  'en' : {
      'home' : 'Home',
      'sobre' : 'About us',
      'equipe' : 'Team',
      'ferramentas' : 'Tools',
      'exchanges' : 'Supported Exchanges',
      'contato' : 'Contact',
  },
  'pt' : {
      'home' : 'Home',
      'sobre' : 'Quem somos',
      'equipe' : 'Equipe',
      'ferramentas' : 'Ferramentas',
      'exchanges' : 'Exchanges Suportadas',
      'contato' : 'Contato',
  }
};

$(function(){
  $('#year').change(function(){
      var lang = $(this).val();

      $('.lang').each(function(index, element){
          $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="language">
  <select id="year">
      <option value="pt" id="pt">PT</option>
      <option value="en" id="en">EN</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active" data-menuanchor="home">
            <a class="nav-link lang" href="#home" key="home">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item"  data-menuanchor="quem-somos">
            <a class="nav-link lang" href="#quem-somos" key="sobre">Quem Somos</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item"  data-menuanchor="equipe">
            <a class="nav-link lang" href="#equipe" key="equipe">Equipe</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item"  data-menuanchor="ferramentas">
            <a class="nav-link lang" href="#ferramentas" key="ferramentas">Ferramentas</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item"  data-menuanchor="exchanges">
            <a class="nav-link lang" href="#exchanges" key="exchanges">Exchanges Suportadas</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item"  data-menuanchor="contato" key="contato">
            <a class="nav-link lang" href="#contato">Contato</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

> #### Nota em relação ao atributo `key`
>
> Eu não usaria o atributo `key` para definir a chave do objeto, já que é um atributo inválido de acordo com a especificação do HTML5. Ao invés de `key`, prefira usar `data-key`. :)

Comment: Então colocando o data-key muda alguma coisa

Comment: Técnicamente, sim, já que o `key` é um atributo inválido e poderá causar erros durante a validação do HTML do seu website. Mas como expliquei na resposta, o erro não se deve ao nome do atributo. O `data-key` é preferível somente como uma **boa prática**. :)

Comment: coloquei o data key ou seja nessa linha deveria trocar o key por data-key 
 $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);

eu fiz a alteração aqui e não funcionou em meu site bem estranho isso será que é porque estou usando o plugin chamado full-page js

Comment: Você deveria trocar no seu HTML  também. Basicamente, ao invés de `key`, usar `data-key`. E no JavaScript, ao invés de capturar o atributo `key`, capturar o atributo `data-key`. Mas devo reiterar que o não funcionamento do código **não se deve a isso**.

Comment: então não funcionou mas aqui seu exemplo funciona que estranho esse é o site se puder dar uma olhada olha só http://creativestudiodesigner.com.br/test/reactioon/

Comment: O problema se deve porque você está usando um `select` customizado. Se você remover a classe `select-hidden` do `<select>` e mudar o idioma diretamente por lá, irá funcionar. No entanto, esse não é mais o escopo dessa pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda eu abri outro tópico referente a esse problema de fato como estilizei o campo ele nao funciona abri aqui se puder me ajudar lá https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/383187/problema-com-select-box-para-mudan%C3%A7a-de-idioma